# Angular7: MatButtonModule doesn't load

Tags: angular, module, angular7

I begin with Angular7 and Material fwk, I load some modules on my app module :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatToolbarModule, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule, MatIconModule, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

All these modules are loaded and I can use them, except mat-button

```
<mat-toolbar class="menu" color="primary">
  <mat-icon>public</mat-icon>
  <div class="fill-space"></div>
  <mat-button>
    <mat-icon>explore</mat-icon>
  </mat-button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I got this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-button' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
```

I've try differents tricks, delete/clean and reinstall but all the material components works except mat button.

Material and Angular in package.json are in 7.0.1 version

Thank you for your time/help

Answer (score 4):

Typical usage for mat-button is an an attribute of a standard button element, like so:

```
<h3>Basic Buttons</h3>
<div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-button>Basic</button>
    <button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
    <button mat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
    <button mat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
    <button mat-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    <a mat-button routerLink=".">Link</a>
</div>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples

Comment: I've try this solution, i don't have the error but the button is not stylised (like the module isn't loaded)

Comment: Just tried a similar example to yours on a project I'm working on: `<button mat-raised-button color="secondary" mat-dialog-close><mat-icon>explore</mat-icon>></button>`, works like a charm.  Sorry my suggestion didn't help.

Comment: You forgot to import the theme. Follow the instructions (especially #4 ) on this page to make it work : https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You should use mat-button as an attribute for your button!

```
  <button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```